# I cannot get authorized at GitHub in Android Studio when creating a token

Tags: java, kotlin, github, token

I created a token at GitHub and went to Android Studio to add this token. In Version Control GitHub settings I clicked on "Add account". It redirected me to JetBrains in my browser and asked me to get authorized at GitHub. I entered my login and password, but it did nothing but emptied the fields as if I entered this wrong. How can I add an account directly in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I would recommend you to got to the github option in  GIT icon in the toolbar. if you cannot find it then it must be in the VCS named option. Since my rank is not enough to post photos,so these links should help you

[go to git option or VCS option in toolbar. find github option in the dropdown and select share on github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyMdB.jpg)

then select login with token and it should take you to your github page on your browser where it generates an auth token which you can copy and paste in the dialog box and verify. Hope this Helped!

[select Login with token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uafv.jpg)
[Now type the copied token and add your account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsIWz.jpg)

Comment: if you need to create screenshots, try to make them with a proper tool directly on you computer (usually the operating system has some support for the PrtScr key to create screenshots). Then also make sure you crop the screenshot to the minimum useful size, cut off any extra stuff around the thing you want to show. And finally you can try to resize it in case the resolution is too high - but don't make it so small that text gets unreadable ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting and select version control then select github and add button use login with token[image]

then when click will show dialog for add token you generate it from version control
[image]

you can try these steps

Comment: Eventually I did the same using hot keys and it worked!